# What is the SDK 1.9 fix for and Beam(2.0) SDK replacement for InProcessPipeline runner?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Digging through comments in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41465231/pubsubreader-failed-with-nullpointerexception-when-executed-with-inprocesspipeli), it appears that InProcessPipelineRunner is

A) Currently broken for PubSub reads in SDK 1.9, with a fix forthcoming

B) Going to be replaced in the Beam SDK

Could someone provide information on:

A) When a fix for InProcessPipeline runner will be available?  How can we track progress?

B) What will provide the run-local functionality for unbounded sources, particularly PubSub, in the Beam SDK(2.0)?

Comment: The InProcessPipeline runner has been renamed to DirectRunner in the latest Beam release. This should work seamlessly with PubSub.

Answer (score 2):

The `InProcessPipelineRunner` has been renamed to `DirectRunner` for the upcoming *Apache Beam 2.0 SDK* and continues to provide the same functionality.